# Android Things - can't use Awareness API

Tags: android, google-play-services, raspberry-pi3, android-things, google-awareness

I have the same code with a lower version (9.4.0) working on the phone but for some reason it won't work on RPi3? My build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.4-devpreview'
```

The manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The method

```
private void getWeather() {

    // Check for permission first
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Fine Location Permission not yet granted");

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    } else {
        System.out.println("else of getWeather()");
        Log.i(TAG, "Fine Location permission already granted");

        // Weather
        Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<WeatherResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull WeatherResult weatherResult) {
                        if (!weatherResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not detect weather info");
                            mWeatherTextView.setText("Could not detect weather info");
                            mWeatherTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            System.out.println("NO WEATHER INFO");
                            return;
                        }
                        System.out.println("WEATHER INFO REC'D");
                        Weather weather = weatherResult.getWeather();
                        mWeatherTextView.setText(weather.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

The logcat

```
08-15 23:46:09.504 411-432/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.example.cartier.thingsaware) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
08-15 23:46:09.594 411-1124/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.iotlauncher/com.android.iotlauncher.IoTLauncher) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:389 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.notifyAppStopped:4456 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityStoppedLocked:1252 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityStopped:6902 
08-15 23:46:11.780 411-479/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
08-15 23:46:35.798 3687-3687/? I/System.out: else of getWeather()
08-15 23:46:35.798 3687-3687/? I/MainActivity: Fine Location permission already granted
```

For some reason it stops after telling me the permission is granted. The app doesn't crash though, I have an OnClickListener that calls getWeather() so I can repeatedly click but never get any snapshot data. I'm using the same API key that works on the phone...

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html) the Awareness API is supported on the AndroidThings & I've seen projects were people claim to have used Nearby & other APIs in the list. Has anyone had success with the Awareness API on AndroidThings?

After updating to play services 11.0.0 the app opens the immediately closes & the logcat now shows

```
08-17 18:13:28.510 3148-3148/? I/System.out: onCreate
08-17 18:13:28.615 410-432/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.cartier.thingsaware/.MainActivity: +1s45ms
08-17 18:13:28.665 410-525/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.iotlauncher/com.android.iotlauncher.IoTLauncher) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:389 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.notifyAppStopped:4456 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityStoppedLocked:1252 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityStopped:6902 
08-17 18:13:28.881 410-432/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.example.cartier.thingsaware) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
08-17 18:13:28.990 3148-3148/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3148 SIG: 9
08-17 18:13:29.047 410-929/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.cartier.thingsaware (pid 3148) has died
08-17 18:13:29.047 410-525/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{9cbd0a u0 com.example.cartier.thingsaware/com.example.cartier.thingsaware.MainActivity}
08-17 18:13:29.048 410-525/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.example.cartier.thingsaware/com.example.cartier.thingsaware.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1780 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack> 
08-17 18:13:29.083 638-638/? I/AndroidThingsLauncher: Peripheral I/O ports 
08-17 18:13:29.083 638-638/? I/AndroidThingsLauncher: GPIO
```

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of AndroidThings? `0.5.0` with Play Services `11` https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html

Comment: Thanks @Blundell. Tried to flash 0.5.0 several times but no luck with it. Followed the ThingsConsole directions: create product (certain I have the right SOM & left 32MB OEM default) > config product > build device image (with empty bundle) > download & flash but each time the screen is just blank. Did you do anything special to create your RPi3 build?

Answer (score 1):

Overall, Android Things requires a minimum Play Services client version of `11.0.0`. This is the version where the IoT variant of Play Services was introduced. This is noted in the documentation under [Support for Google Services](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#google-services).

For best results, you should match the library version to the exact version bundled with the preview release you are running. You can find those version numbers on the [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html).

Comment: Thanks @Devunwired for the feedback. Now with Play Services 11.0.0 the app opens & immediately closes displaying the launcher page? See the new logcat above. Things version I have (0.4.1) wasn't downloaded from the console but directly from the web page like all the previous releases. Flashed version 0.5.0 (three times) as Blundell suggested but always boots to a blank screen? Used an empty bundle each time & could adb in to see the package list but no video output so went back to 0.4.1? Any ideas on how to proceed?