# Android Things - Unable to get Weather and Location

Tags: android, android-things, google-awareness

I'm trying to use the Google Awareness API in my IoT Project, however, when calling the Weather and Location API I'm receiving TIMEOUT errors.

Gradle:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:11.0.4'
provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.5.1-devpreview'`

Manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

API Call:

```
Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<WeatherResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull WeatherResult weatherResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Weather result received: " + weatherResult.getStatus());
                Log.d(TAG, "Weather result code" + weatherResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                Log.d(TAG, "Weather result message" + weatherResult.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                if (weatherResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Weather weather = weatherResult.getWeather();
                    Log.d(TAG, "weather: " + weather);
                    int[] conditions = weather.getConditions();
                }
            }
        });
```

Logcat:

`09-28 16:10:37.557 3234-3234/com.iotunicamp.smartmirror D/DataProviderService: Weather result received: Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}
09-28 16:10:37.558 3234-3234/com.iotunicamp.smartmirror D/DataProviderService: Weather result code 15
09-28 16:10:37.559 3234-3234/com.iotunicamp.smartmirror D/DataProviderService: Weather result message null`

The same code works fine in the Android device.

PS: The internet is working fine on my iot device, I have a code that download a file as part of the project and it works.

Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Comment: did you register your IoT device on Google Console API?

Comment: did you restart or `adb -g` the device to enable the permissions?

Comment: @ItzikSamara my API key has no device restrictions on Google Console API, how do I register my device on it?

Comment: @Blundell yes! Tried many times indeed.

Comment: Do you have location, or is it looking up something that is `null`?

Comment: @NickFelker What o you mean? the getLocation returns Timeout, I don't pass anything for it, just used the API call

Comment: Maybe the API is unable to get the location because it's doing a GPS lookup and failing?

Comment: Run the code on a phone - to sanity check it is not a hardware issue

Comment: @NickFelker probably.. but there's no log indicating that

Comment: @Blundellyes, I already did and it works on phone..

Comment: What hardware board are you using?

Comment: @Blundell a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get the Awareness API to work either [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703282/android-things-cant-use-awareness-api?rq=1). The app opens then immediately closes on RPi3 but runs fine on phone. Have you had any success yet?

Comment: @JC23 Unfortunately not :( . I had to re-design my application to communicate with a phone and get the location from there (using an app and firebase)